# Removing comma after ibid in oscola biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere - I haven't been able to find an appropriate answer so far. (Also I'm new to Latex and to this community so apologies for any infelicities).

I'm using *oscola biblatex*, so far very happily. The one issue I have is comma placement after *ibid*. A correct *ibid* reference in oscola should read: ibid 4. Sometimes I get that; sometimes a comma is incorrectly inserted following *ibid* and I can't work out why.

Here's an example of what I get:

[image: screenshot of example ibid citations]

(The seeming pattern of adding a comma on the second and subsequent *ibid* references isn't always repeated - in another document the first *ibid* ref sometimes also includes a comma.)

And here's the MWE that produces those results:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=oscola]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Reference 1.\autocite{godziak} 

Ibid reference.\autocite[1]{godziak}

Ibid reference.\autocite[2]{godziak} 

Reference 2.\autocite{home}

Ibid reference.\autocite[2]{home}

Ibid reference.\autocite[3]{home} 

Ibid reference.\autocite[45]{home}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I've recreated the error using `biblatex-examples.bib`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=oscola]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

    Reference 1.\autocite{companion} 

    Ibid reference.\autocite[1]{companion}

    Ibid reference.\autocite[2]{companion} 

    Reference 2.\autocite{knuth:ct}

    Ibid reference.\autocite[2]{knuth:ct}

    Ibid reference.\autocite[3]{knuth:ct} 

    Ibid reference.\autocite[45]{knuth:ct}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I've added in `test.bib` here just in case it's still useful.

```
@report{godziak,
title = {Data and Research on Human Trafficking: Bibliography of Research-Based Literature},
author = {Godziak, Elzbieta M. and Bump, Michah N.},
date = {2008-09}
}

@report{home,
title = {Setting the {{Boundaries}}: {{Reforming}} the law on sex offences, {{Volume}} 1},
timestamp = {2015-11-05T14:26:44Z},
author = {{Home Office}},
date = {2000-07},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: This looks like a bug.  You can also see, that the comma is omitted only in the two first `ibid` instances.

Comment: Also, please use `biblatex-examples.bib` or post `test.bib`.  Currently we cannot reproduce what you posted.

Comment: As you can see, the output is also a bit fishy in other regards. It leaves a space before the final full stop. AFAIK `oscola` has last been updated in 2014 and so it might also have problems with the more recent changes in `biblatex` (version 3.3).

Comment: Sorry, I'll add `test.bib` in now. The space before the final full stop is indeed a bit off - it also recurs inconsistently amongst references in a larger document.

Comment: Also, thanks CarLaTex for recreating the error using `biblatex-examples.bib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some very sophisticated code to get postnote handling right. It seems as though in very special cases the code set up for that task "spills over" to the next footnote. Use

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
\makeatother
```

to avoid that.

If you want to suppress the comma after "ibid" you need to add `\bbx@unsetpostnotedelim` to `footcite:ibid`

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:ibid}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ ( test {\iffieldundef{userc}} 
                 or test {\iffieldundef{postnote}}) 
               and not 
                 test{\iffieldequals{entrysubtype}{\subtypecourtrules}} }%
  {\printtext[bibhyperlink]{\iftoggle{bbx@capibid}{}{\midsentence}\bibstring{ibidem}}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}%
   \bbx@unsetpostnotedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:refonlyfull}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, moewe. I added your code to my preamble and it made all the citations consistent - but it did so by making sure *ibid* is always followed by a comma. Is it possible to make it so that it's never followed by a comma?

Comment: @Owain I have added some additional code that should take care of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately when I add in your second code block all the "ibids" appear as, e.g., "ibid@unsetpostnotedelim, 39". However, I played around a bit and found that if I amend your first codeblock slightly (and included just that block) I get the "ibid" without a comma I was looking for. The change I made was to amend `\bbx@resetpostnotedelim` to `\bbx@unsetpostnotedelim`.

Comment: @Owain OK. Did you place the second code block between a `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` pair like the first one? I'm not sure if your solution may not get rid of commas where they are actually needed.

Comment: Thanks. I did, but it was a separate `\makeatletter / \makeatother` pair. When I put both codeblocks between the same `makeatletter / \makeatother` pair the commas do disappear. Is that perhaps the better solution?

Comment: @Owain It should not matter if you have the blocks between the same pair or between separate pairs of `\makeatletter`/`makeatother`. I would say that my solution is preferable to placing `\bbx@unsetpostnotedelim` in `\AtEveryCitekey`, but use whatever works for you.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your help, it's much appreciated.